# avoid changing javascript parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a simple button to post comment like this

```
<button onclick="postComment('384',this);">Post</button>
```

in function `postComment(post_id,element)` :

384 means post_id that be commented

I know user can easily changing `'384'` number with something else, ie.`'1000'` with `firebug` or other developer tools. it cause they comment on post that have an `id 1000`

how to prevent this?

Comment: If 384 is the only one that the user can comment on, then the server should know that and if it gets any other ID, it knows the response is not valid. Web clients are utterly untrustworthy, so treat them that way. ;-)

Comment: Do not handle ids on creating client-side. Instead, send a request to your backend telling it to post a new comment. The backend should figure out the id, potentially responding with it. It seems like *you need to do more research on architecture*.

Comment: @RobG: yes, suppose 384 is the only one that the user can comment on.. should we check them every time?

Comment: @Niels Abildgaard: have you better approach for this?

for example there are some post div like this

<div id=1>POST 1</div>
<div id=2>POST 2</div>
.....................
<div id=10>POST 10</div>

Then every post has comment input and submit button, what is your method to know that the user comment on certain div without posting the parameter?

Comment: Ah! Now I understand. But what would be the problem if the user deliberately changed the number in the code and his comment ended up somewhere random? You have to guarantee that he has the rights before posting it, but other than that I don't see the problem. This is similar to visiting a random url on a website: generally not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call the function with a parameter. Instead try to let the function itself search for the latest already posted comment id (in a db or elsewhere) and increment that value.

Comment: how can the function itself search for the latest already posted comment id? please help

Comment: That really depends on your configuration. Where do you store comments and in which format?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with databases but I assume each entry has an ID, right? If that holds, you can simply lookup the ID corresponding to the entry of a single comment.

Comment: yes, each entry has an ID. but how can I simply lookup the ID corresponding to the entry of a single comment? please show me with php code

Comment: One can not simply lookup the ID of the value of a single comment, since multiple comments can have the same text. More variables are needed to ensure each db entry is unique if you want to lookup its ID. Variables like the name of the author, the date/time, etc... Where do you need this for?

Answer (score 0):

on your function:

```
postComment(post_id,element)
```

it means you have

`INSERT INTO post ('id', ..., ...) VALUES ($post_id, ..., ...);`

---

recode and fix it (depend on your logic) to

```
postComment(element)
```

check if have insertion from ID on javascript.